# Lost Exchange Account

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app

I transferred some bitcoin from my coinbase account to another exchange to purchase some ethereum.  At that time coinbase did not have ethereum.  However, I do not remember the exchange that I used.  I have the exchange password written down in a secure location so if I can track which exchange I sent it to I can recover the ETH.  The transfer from coinbase is listed on the coinbase website.  Is there a way for me to use the wallet ID which I sent the BTC to to find out which exchange is holding my ETH?

Thanks in advance for your assistance in helping me overcome my own disorganization.

Answer (score -1):

Man, maybe the answer will shock you, but... your amount of crypto is probably lost.
I say ''probably'' and not for sure.
the options may be 2:
1. the transaction was too small, so miners didn't pick it
2. it's fault of the exchange
I don't suggest you to use coinbase, I suggest you buy on spectrocoin -> https://spectrocoin.com/en/ 
And to trade from crypto to crypto using Binance -> https://www.binance.com/?ref=16821839
Anyway here's a guide to choose the best exchange -> https://medium.com/@bitfinexed/coinbase-insider-trading-litecoin-edition-be64ead3facc